# Share namespace of caller with imported module

Tags: python, module, namespaces

**The short version of the question first:**

Assume we have a module called "module" and a python script "caller.py" that imports module.
Is it possible to share the globals() namespace of caller.py with the module?
Such that i could do something like this:

module.py

```py
def print_handle(fkt_name):
    globals()[fkt_name]
```

caller.py:

```py
def function_from_caller():
    return 0

import module
module.print_handle('function_from_caller')
# which then returns something like:
# <function __main__.function_from_caller()>
```

---

**Long version:**
As far as I understand, the scope of imported module in python is restricted to that module.
Anything that is not defined in the module or imported somehow is unknown to it.

If a module is imported I can share it's namespace with the namespace of caller by either specifically naming the functions of interest with

```
from module import function_of_interest
```

or to share the full namespace

```
from module import *
```

However, as far as I know it is not possible to achieve this the other way around, or is it?
Can I pass the namespace from the caller function to the module in any way?
I.e. with something like

```
pi = 3
import module with pi
```

or in case I want to pass everything

```
import module with *
```

If this is not possible as suspected, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the reason why you should do that.

if the module has anb attribute `a` in it, you can just do

`module.a = 12`

If you have many attributes, just use `setattr(module, AttrName, AttrValue)` in a `for` loop.

MMan

Comment: It's been a while now, but the challenge was to find a way to call a function from a different module (hence, it wasn't in global) not by the function handle but by a string which is the same string that is used in the module to define the function.

Comment: Ah, and additionally it might not even be in a module but may be user defined in  ```__main__```. This complicated the problem since this requires that the functions defined in ```__main__``` are available to the module "caller.py" in my example.

Comment: I ended up adding these function to global with the following but hoped for a more elegant solution: ```def import_functions(func): for item in func: name = item.__name__; globals()[name] = item```